# uploading video file to firebase storage

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to upload video file to firebase storage. for some reason the file does not get uploaded to the storage what am i missing? 
I'm using Mediafilepicker plugin to pick a video from the gallery then send that video file to firebase storage

I havent found similar issues (nativescript-angular)

```
    let mediafilepicker = new Mediafilepicker();
mediafilepicker.openVideoPicker(options);

mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", (res) => {

    let results = res.object.get('results');

    if (results) {
        this.videoFileUrl = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            let result = results[i];

            let file = result.file;
            this.vidPath = file;

            this.vid = file

            let filename = (new Date).getTime().toString() + ".mp4";
            let new_path = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path, "/app/images/");
            let folder = fs.Folder.fromPath(new_path);
            let path = fs.path.join(folder.path, file);
            this.videoFileUrl.push(file);
            console.log(path);


    }
}

});

mediafilepicker.on("error", (res) => {
    let msg = res.object.get('msg');
    console.log(msg);
});

mediafilepicker.on("cancel", (res) => {
    let msg = res.object.get('msg');
    console.log(msg);
});

setInterval(() => {
    // require view to be updated
    this.ref.markForCheck();
}, 500);
```

}

shows 0 errors

I expect it to upload the video

Comment: Make sure the `File` in the specified path exists. In my experience `File.exists()` yields unreliable results. It's better to look at the `size` of the `File`

Comment: @NeryOrtez yeah that solved the problem was with the file path,,, i have a video file that i pick from device using mediafilepicker  pluginand also want to upload it to firebase storage. will update my question with new code

Comment: I don't see where the `openGaller` and `openGallery` connects or how are passing the path from a place to the other. Also, try to use better naming on your methods :)

Comment: @NeryOrtez i tried to save the video source inside a folder in my app directory and then send it to firebase storage , but it still showing that the folder was uploaded with 0 bytes i even put an actual video inside my  app directory and uploaded it but still showing the 0 bytes thing again...i updated my question with the new code am using you can check it out

Comment: Any updates? Having the same issue